# SignInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync fails to log in user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

In the context of ASP.NET Identity in ASP.NET Core and OAuth, I have the following snippet in a login callback:

```
var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
if (info == null)
{
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
}

var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(
    info.LoginProvider,
    info.ProviderKey,
    isPersistent: true);

if (result.Succeeded)
{
    // ...
```

For some reason that I'm unable to determine, `result` always comes back with status `Failed`, even though I do log into the external provider correctly (evidently, since a refresh of the external page suddenly shows me as logged on).

The only information I have except that the login attempt failed, is that it is *not* because any of `IsLockedOut`, `RequiresTwoFactor` or `IsNotAllowed`, since those flags are also `false` on the `result` object.

How do I obtain more information about what went wrong?

---

Update:

Following suggestions by @Dmitry, I've enabled quite aggressive logging, but I still fail to find anything valuable. The only thing I get in my logs between the successful fetch of `info` and the subsequent failed login attempt, is the following from my db context:

> 2017-07-04T22:45:14.2847287+02:00 0HL633KNRMVO7 [INF] Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@__get_Item_0='?' (Size = 450), @__get_Item_1='?' (Size = 450)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>   SELECT TOP(1) [e].[LoginProvider], [e].[ProviderKey], [e].[ProviderDisplayName], [e].[UserId]
>   FROM [AspNetUserLogins] AS [e]
>   WHERE ([e].[LoginProvider] = @__get_Item_0) AND ([e].[ProviderKey] = @__get_Item_1) (6438bdd5)

Executing that in MSSQL Management Studio I get an empty result set, which I suspect might be a problem, but I have no idea why, or how to fix it. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Enable debug logging and check logs.

Comment: @Dmitry care to expand on *how* to do that? Where do I configure logging? Where does the logging output end up?

Comment: When you login with the external provider, is that login success captured in the database? I forget the table name on top of my head, but one of the Identity tables will have the authentication information for that provider along with Id column for your User. If that table is empty, it could be as simple as your Credentials not having access to write to that table/database. This maybe a bit of a long shot, but worth a try as you have nothing to go on right now. The only other thing I can suggest at this point is to generate PBD's for identity and step through that code.

Comment: @Bojan: All tables related to ASP.NET Identity, except AspNetUsers, are empty. IIUC, one of them (`AspNetUserLogins`?) should have a row for a successful login, is that correct? Does the fact that I don't have such a row indicate an error at sign-in time, or at config time?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are missing a call to `UserManager.AddLoginAsync` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497534(v=vs.108).aspx), which will populate the `AspNetUserLogins` table.

Answer (score -1):

Your `Startup.cs` contains `Configure(...)` method with something like `loggerFactory.AddConsole(...)` in first lines.

Logging configuration may be set in code or read from configuration file (`appsettings.json`) - it depends on your project.

Check you current logging config and set level to `Debug`. Then restart app and check console output while logging in.

Docs: [Introduction to Logging in ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging)

Comment: Thanks. Logging gave some information, but not much; please see my update.